Freeze, Token two-level smart contract
I need to create a token on Solana using a two-level smart contract so that platforms like Dexscreener do not display the alert: "This token is freezable."
Implementation Idea:
First Level: A standard token without freeze authority.
Second Level: A custom smart contract that controls token transfers and implements the freezing function at the logic level, hiding it from standard checks.
Is it possible?

what you're describing is transfer hook token extension. It is not freeze authority, it is a custom transfer logic in your program. But i'm not really sure that different DEXes will be compatible with transfer hook

Information about whether an SPL mint has the freeze_authority revoked or not is stored on the token mint account.

It's not possible to hide this. As long as the freeze authority exists, there's possibility that this authority can freeze the token.

I heard that it is possible to do.
